# Manpages not showing output properly

Tags: lxterminal

I changed my Terminal colours and now when I open any manpage for help, it's not showing the proper output. But when I switch back to the default colours, manpages display properly. Why is it so?

[Link to full image on Imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGmT3.png)

[image]

Comment: Add a screenshot, please. Upload to imgur and add a link.

Comment: Post the changes you made =)

Comment: I have added screenshot @muru.please do refer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the bold text color matches the background color: just change the bold text color to something different from black in the Terminal profile's settings.

Comment: @TusharChauhan If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking the mark under the upvotes count. When you'll have more reputation also consider upvoting helpful answers to your questions (or to other's questions, or other's question) by clicking the arrow on the top of the upvotes counts.